# TerminalServer Property in MSI Installers

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, terminal-services

we are trying to create an MSI Installer for an app which under Windows Server 2003. The app needs users to be able to log on via Remote Desktop. Using the "TerminalServer" property looked like the correct test to ensure that's the case, but this returns "false" on machines which do have the right OS with Terminal Service running and which allow users to connect remotely.

What are we missing here?

Thanks!
Armin

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you actually do need Terminal Services installed and "on"; remote desktop might not be enough. Try also RemoteAdminTS. MSI documentation suggests they are mutually exclusive.

Run the MSI file with /l*v to find out what properties are set to what values.